# Error Parsing Data java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread when populating Google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask

Ok, right now I am trying to populate a Google Map given a Name, Lat and Long. These values are coming in from a database via PHP script. This is all good and working fine. But I've run into a problem: I am populating the map with markers in an AsyncTask. This is here I get the error

`07-10 14:47:41.035: E/log_tag(21034): Error Parsing Data java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread`

This is the **only** error I get and it doesn't specify where it is. I'm guessing it is because the map isn't being populated on the main thread? But I can't do network stuff on the main thread, so I can't remove it from the AsyncTask. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks

Code:

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    MapLocations myTask = new MapLocations();
    myTask.execute();

}

private class MapLocations extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String msg = "Done";
    ArrayList<Marker> arrayOfMarkers;

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "MYPHPSCRIPT");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
            // resultView.setText("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // counter++;

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(json.getString("PlaceLat")), Double.parseDouble(json
                                .getString("PlaceLong")))).title(
                        json.getString("PlaceTitle")));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

The error is based around this code
 try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

```
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // counter++;

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(json.getString("PlaceLat")), Double.parseDouble(json
                                .getString("PlaceLong")))).title(
                        json.getString("PlaceTitle")));
            }
```

Comment: that's what onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are for

Comment: `it doesn't specify where it is`. but it does. you are simply hiding it when you only log `Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());` instead of a more complete `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right here

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(json.getString("PlaceLat")), Double.parseDouble(json
                                .getString("PlaceLong")))).title(
                        json.getString("PlaceTitle")));
```

you cannot add stuff to the map off the main thread as the error clearly states. create a list of points then pass it to your `onPostExecute` and do the plotting there